# Logparser for Linux (syslog) logs?

Tags: linux, syslog, logparser

I'm looking for something like logparser on Windows. 
Requirements:

- simple tool, not engine like octopusy or sth,
- able to select on text in message part,
- start search in log from checkpoint on previous search.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LogWatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/)?  It comes as standard on many modern Linux systems, can search by eg date range, and finds and summarises just about anything odd.

If you want more regexp customisability and easier setup, [swatch](http://swatch.sourceforge.net/) might be more up your street.